# Can I have a shared Confluence page with an external vendor?

Tags: confluence

Is there a way to have a page on Confluence shared with an external vendor? We are looking for a joint place where each person can put in meeting items before/during & after meeting.

Tried looking into the section named "Restrictions", but could not find anything there.